# How to add images into a list

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I have multiple images in my program. And I wish to display them randomly on the screen. I tried doing this by putting the images into the list and then selecting random positions for them. However when I assign a variale for the picture and add it into the list it doesn't work.
Heres an example.

```
room1 = pygame.image.load("room1.png").convert()
room_list = []
room_list.append(room1)
```

Then somewhere after the main loop I do

```
for i in range(0,100):
    positionx = random.randrange(0,400)
    positiony = random.randrange(0,400)
    position = [positionx,positiony]
    x = random.randrange(room_list)
    screen.blit(x,position)
```

When I do run this, the error is that it must be a int not a string.

BTW the room_list has more than one image in it.

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

Comment: Best practice is to post the error Traceback along with your code when asking a question.

Comment: What is your error message, something like `int() argument must be a string`? Because `randrange()` want's an integer not a list. Check the documentation for `randrange()` : )

Comment: Maybe use ```random.choice(room_list)``` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [randrange](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.randrange) docs, the function doesn't select an element randomly from a list, but rather returns a random integer from a certain range.

The way to call it would be: `x = room_list[random.randrange(len(room_list))`.

Alternatively, and closer to your issue, you could use the [choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice) function like so: `x = random.choice(room_list)`.

Comment: oh ok ill try that.

Comment: So if I use random.choice  it will  just pick the image right